# iterating over an unordered_set

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-set

I need help iterating over an unordered map in C++. I am trying to put the elements of the set into an array so that I can sort the array.

```cpp
for(auto it=s.begin();it!=s.end();it++){
    a[i]=*it;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: What is your *question*? What is the obstacles that is preventing you from doing so? Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) should be helpful.

Comment: Why don't you just insert the elements from your unordered set onto an ordered one ?

Comment: I voted to close this question because no question is being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are using many differen terms here.

- unordered_set
- unordered_map
- set
- array

So, it is a little bit unclear what you really want to do.

If you have a `std::unordered_set`and want to put the data into a `std::set`, then you can simply use its range constructor and write something like `std::set<int> ordered(s.begin(),s.end());`

The same would work with a `std::vector` which has also a range constructor. Arrays, either C-style or C++ `std::array` are more complicated, because you need to know the size of the original data in advance. Because: Arrays have a compile time definde fixed size.

For sorting `std::maps` or `std::unordered_map`s according to their "value" and not the key, you need to use a `std::multiset` with a special sorting functor or lambda. If you edit your question and give more details, then I will provide source code to you.